# problem with infinite loop in function hook useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with an infinite loop on my hook,
I'm passing the data of the local JSON breakfast. If you are iterating with map the data and I am taking it to paint a menu of buttons.
If I remove the data at the end of the function, and leave the empty array, it sends me the following error:

```
const BreakfastComponent = () => {

   const breakfast = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Sandwich de jamón y queso",
      price: '35',
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/ynC9xHZ/sandjc.png",

    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Jugo Natural",
      price: '15',
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/8mrd4MK/orangejuice.png",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Café americano",
      price: '20',
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/nsj1GL0/americancoffe.png",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Café con leche",
      price: '28',
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/GRPBm7j/coffeandmilk.png",
    }
  ];


  const [stateProduct, setStateProduct] = useState([ ]);


  useEffect(() => {

    setStateProduct(breakfast);
  }, [breakfast]);

  return (

      <section className="databreakfast">
        {stateProduct.map((element, item) =>
          <ButtonsBComponent
            key={item}
            {...element}

          />
        )}
        </section>



  )
};

export default BreakfastComponent;
```

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'breakfast'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple, you have `breakfast` array as a dependency to `useEffect` and in `useEffect` you are setting the breakfast array itself. Now since the const breakfast array is declared inside the component, a new reference to it is generated everytime and since useEffect sets the array in state, it re-renders and on next re-render the comparison for `breakfast` array fails since the reference has changed.

The solution is simple, you don't need to have the const array in the component and also you don't need to use useEffect

```
const breakfast = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Sandwich de jamón y queso",
      price: '35',
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/ynC9xHZ/sandjc.png",

    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Jugo Natural",
      price: '15',
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/8mrd4MK/orangejuice.png",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Café americano",
      price: '20',
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/nsj1GL0/americancoffe.png",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Café con leche",
      price: '28',
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/GRPBm7j/coffeandmilk.png",
    }
  ];

const BreakfastComponent = () => {

  const [stateProduct, setStateProduct] = useState(breakfast);


  return (

      <section className="databreakfast">
        {stateProduct.map((element, item) =>
          <ButtonsBComponent
            key={item}
            {...element}

          />
        )}
        </section>



  )
};

export default BreakfastComponent;
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect`'s second argument is an array of state/hooks to be watched and when they change, to run the effect.  Since your `breakfast` is a const, I'm guessing you just want the original `stateProduct` to be `breakfast`.  So instead of using `[]` as the default, use `breakfast`.

```
const [stateProduct, setStateProduct] = useState(breakfast);
```

Also, probably a good idea to declare `const breakfast ...` outside of your react functional component so it doesn't re-declare it on every re-render.