# React Native: Timer keeps reseting

Tags: javascript, react-native, countdowntimer

I am trying to do a countdown timer but after it gets to 1 it resets to 5 when its supposed to go to '00:00', I don't know where I am going wrong please may someone help me

**This is my code:**

```js
const CountDown = () => {
    const RESET_INTERVAL_S = 5;

    const formatTime = (time) =>
        `${String(Math.floor(time / 60)).padStart(2, "0")}:${String(
            time % 60
        ).padStart(2, "0")}`;

    const Timer = ({ time }) => {
        const timeRemain = RESET_INTERVAL_S - (time % RESET_INTERVAL_S);

        return (
            <>
                <Text>{formatTime(timeRemain)}</Text>
            </>
        );
    };

    const IntervalTimerFunctional = () => {
        const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

        console.log("The time is", time);

        useEffect(() => {
            const timerId = setInterval(() => {
                setTime((t) => t + 1);
            }, 1000);
            return () => clearInterval(timerId);
        }, []);

        return <Timer time={time} />;
    };

    return <IntervalTimerFunctional />;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is a perfect solution but this could work:

You could stop your timer when it reaches its maximum value:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((t) => {
            if(t + 1 === RESET_INTERVAL_S) {
                clearInterval(timerId)
            }

            return t + 1;
        });
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timerId);

}, []);
```

And display "00:00" when you have reached the limit:

```
    <Text>{time === RESET_INTERVAL_S ? "00:00" : formatTime(timeRemain)}</Text>
```

Here is a working [example](https://snack.expo.io/@kamiranoff/vengeful-waffles)

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
     const timerId = setInterval(() => {
     setTime((t) => t + 1);
}, 1000);
     return () => clearInterval(timerId);
}, []);
```

You need to set the value you want to repeat on. If not, this will keep resetting it.

You could also add a condition to check the value of the timer and stop it. like this:

```
{
   time !== 0 ? setTime((t) => t+1): time = 0;
}
```

[Here is a similar problem to yours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155398/problem-with-infinite-loop-in-function-hook-useeffect)

Comment: I already have this in my code but unfortunately it is still lopping